# Deleting records from SQL Server but not resetting PK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I deleted all records from a table on a SQL Server 2014 using the TRUNCATE function, but now new records on this table begin with PK 1.

Is there a way to not reset the primary key so that the new records begin from the last PK + 1?

Comment: I believe `TRUNCATE` resets the identity. Perhaps you can just use the `DELETE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting will work.  But sometimes the time a delete takes can be an issue.  If you have to truncate you can do the following:

1. Get the maximum value from your table and store this in a variable.
2. Truncate the table
3. Reseed the identity to the variable value + 1.

Here is an example.

```
DECLARE @MaxID AS INT;
SELECT @MaxID = MAX(ID) + 1
FROM TableA;

TRUNCATE TABLE TableA;

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.TableA', RESEED, @MaxID);
```

New inserts into the table will now continue from the previous identity value.

Marius

Answer (score 0):

Using `DELETE` seems to work.

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Col VARCHAR)
DECLARE @Num INT = 10,
        @Count INT = 0
WHILE @Count < @Num
BEGIN
INSERT @Tab
VALUES('')
SET @Count = @Count + 1
END
DELETE FROM @Tab
INSERT @Tab
VALUES ('')
SELECT *
FROM @Tab
```